# Differences between nested ANOVA and two-way ANOVA, without a repeated measures structure and a small number of levels per factor

Tags: anova, fixed-effects-model, nested-data, ecology, two-way

My question is rather simple, and it's not so much about R, but about how to analyse a very simple dataset. I have 6 sites, and 2 ecosystem type (3 sites per ecosystem). From each site I have 3 measurements of my response variable. I'm interested in comparing the means between and within ecosystems. How should I analyse this dataset, as a nested ANOVA or a two-way ANOVA?
I've read that a nested ANOVA wouldn't work because my within factor is not random, but a two-way ANOVA is a fully factorial design (all factors are crossed), hence my confusion.

*Sorry if it is a silly question, but I rather do it!*

Also, I've tried the `aov` function, using `/` and `Error`, but Error is used with random factors and I only have three levels (site with 3 observations each) per group (ecosystem).
I can provide an example, but, maybe, it's a simple question.

Comment: I think this is a great question! It is definitely better than guessing. I think you may find exactly what you are looking for [here](https://www.uvm.edu/~statdhtx/StatPages/R/RepeatedMeasuresAnovaR.html).

Comment: Thank you! It was quite helpful